# Using 32 bit .NET assemblies from 64 bit matlab

Tags: c#, .net, matlab, gac

I'm using NET.addAssembly(Namespace) to load a pair of msil assemblies.

One of them gives me this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly <Namespace> or one of its dependencies...
```

When using a 32 bit version of Matlab I don't get this error.
I'd prefer to use a 64 bit version of matlab for this project, any suggestions? And is there a way to choose a specific version of an assembly?

Comment: Where are the assemblies from? If they're yours, can you rebuild them to be AnyCPU?

Comment: I can't rebuild them, they are from ABB, part of the ABB PC SDK.

Comment: I suggest you email ABB and ask if they have an AnyCPU or x64 version then.

Comment: In case you don't have any choice and you must do what you try to do. The solution would be 64-bit proxy assembly loaded from Matlab, communicating by named pipes with server which wraps your 32 bit assembly. I used this approach when had to add a plugin compiled with .Net 4.5 to software compiled with .Net 3.0. It works.